# Radiobuttons in Shiny DataTable for "subselection" of rows/ grouping in one column

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

What I am trying to accomplish is similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43738851/adding-radiobutton-to-select-a-datatable-row-in-shiny?rq=1), but slightly more complicated.

I would like to group the radio buttons into different groups, but in one column so a "subselection" of rows is possible.

Currently only the radio button group with ID "C" works, because the div element is defined for the whole table. I have tried to insert the shiny tags via javascript callback, but I'm only able to insert a radio button for each row or for each column, but not for a subset of multiple rows in one column.

Open to javascript or shiny solutions.

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    title = 'Radio buttons in a table',
    tags$div(id="C",class='shiny-input-radiogroup',DT::dataTableOutput('foo')),
    verbatimTextOutput("test")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    m = matrix(
      c(round(rnorm(24),1), rep(3,12)), nrow = 12, ncol = 3, byrow = F,
      dimnames = list(month.abb, LETTERS[1:3])
    )
    m[, 2] <- rep(c("A","B","C", "D"), each= 3)
    m[, 3] <- paste0('<input type="radio" name="', rep(c("A","B","C", "D"), each= 3),'" value="', month.abb,'"/>')
    m[c(1,4,7,10), 3] <- gsub('/>', 'checked="checked"/>', m[c(1,4,7,10), 3], fixed = T)
    m
    output$foo = DT::renderDataTable(
      m, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', server = FALSE,
      options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE)
      # callback = JS("table.rows().every(function() {
      #           var $this = $(this.node());
      #           $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
      #           $this.addClass('shiny-input-radiogroup');
      #           });
      #           Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
      #           Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
    )
    output$test <- renderPrint(str(input$C))
  }
)
```

**UPDATE:**

The rough structure of my final solution with reactive button selection. The inputs and visuals stay preserved with re-rendering the table (just the first time the input renders as `NULL` which is no particular problem for me).

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    title = "Radio buttons in a table",
    sliderInput("slider_num_rows", "Num Rows", min = 2, max = 12, value = 5),
    tags$div(id = 'placeholder'),
    verbatimTextOutput("test")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    rea <- reactive({
      m = matrix(
        c(round(rnorm(24),1), rep(3,12)), nrow = 12, ncol = 3, byrow = F,
        dimnames = list(month.abb, LETTERS[1:3])
      )

      m[, 2] <- rep(c("A","B","C", "D"), each= 3)
      m[, 3] <- paste0('<input type="radio" name="', rep(c("A","B","C", "D"), each= 3),'" value="', month.abb,'"/>')
      save_sel <- c()
      mon_tes <- c("Jan", "Apr", "Jul", "Oct")
      ab <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
      for (i in 1:4){
        if (is.null(input[[ab[i]]])){
          save_sel[i] <-  mon_tes[i]
        } else {
          save_sel[i] <- input[[ab[i]]]
        }
      }
      sel <- rownames(m) %in% save_sel
      m[sel, 3] <- gsub('/>', 'checked="checked"/>', m[sel, 3], fixed = T)
      m <- m[1:input$slider_num_rows,]
      m
    })

    output$foo = DT::renderDataTable(
      rea(), escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', server = FALSE,
      options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE,
                     columnDefs = list(list(className = 'no_select', targets = 3)))
    )

     observe({
      l <- unique(m[, 2])

      for(i in 1:length(l)) {
        if (i == 1) {
          radio_grp <- div(id = l[i], class = "shiny-input-radiogroup", DT::dataTableOutput("foo"))
        } else {
          radio_grp <- div(id = l[i], class = "shiny-input-radiogroup", radio_grp)
        }
      }
      insertUI(selector = '#placeholder',
               ui = radio_grp)
    })
    output$test <- renderPrint( {
      str(input$A)
      str(input$B)
      str(input$C)
      str(input$D)
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest the `div` elements into each other like this:

```
  ui = fluidPage(
    title = "Radio buttons in a table",
    div(id = "A", class = "shiny-input-radiogroup",
      div(id = "B", class = "shiny-input-radiogroup",
        div(id = "C", class = "shiny-input-radiogroup",
          div(id = "D", class = "shiny-input-radiogroup", DT::dataTableOutput("foo"))    
        )
      )
    ),
```

I also modified `renderText` in order to print all the values.

```
output$test <- renderPrint( {
  str(input$A)
  str(input$B)
  str(input$C)
  str(input$D)
})
```

Here is the result after interacting with the dataTableOutput (selected the `Feb` radio button):

[image]

Please note that the elements will still have `NULL` value until interaction. You can get around this problem though, with an `if` statement, using the default values of radio buttons when the input elements are `NULL`.

**Edit**: You can create the `divs` with a loop like this:

```
l <- unique(m[, 2])

for(i in 1:length(l)) {
  if (i == 1) {
    radio_grp <- div(id = l[i], class = "shiny-input-radiogroup", DT::dataTableOutput("foo"))
  } else {
    radio_grp <- div(id = l[i], class = "shiny-input-radiogroup", radio_grp) 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works like a charm. But what if I have like 100  groups, is it wise to nest  so many `div` elements? And is it possible to dynamically nest these?

Comment: I don't think nesting some `divs` should be a problem. As for "dynamic nesting" you can write a loop for that. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks again! One more question regarding the radio buttons having `NULL` value until interaction. I changed their values in an `observe()` when they are `NULL`. But if I make a selection or change anything, what causes a re-rendering of the table, nothing is shown as selected in any button. Their input values are still the same though. Do you know how to render the table this way with default values or change their visual output accordingly after every rendering to their current values?